# What does the word "credit" mean in the sentence, "Let things drift and you are likely to default and be blacklisted for future credit."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found this sentence in a website without any more context to the sentence. I can't really tell what it means; and I assume with the limited amount of context it could mean more than one thing. I'd appreciate it if you'd help me figure out the sentence's possible meanings.

Comment: [**default**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/default) (v) - *to fail to fulfil an obligation, esp. to make payment when due.* [**blacklist**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blacklist) (v) - *to put someone's name on a blacklist* (noun: *a list of people, countries, etc. who are considered by a particular authority or group to be unacceptable and who should be avoided and not trusted*). [**credit**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/credit) (n) - *a method of paying for goods or services at a later time.* All easily found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let things drift and you are likely to default and be blacklisted for future credit**

**[If you] let things drift** If you allow matters to progress without you controlling them

**You are likely to default** You probably will fail to make a payment

**... and be blacklisted ...** and be put on a list of people who are denied a service

**... for future credit.** The service is being allowed to borrow money

Answer (score 0):

From my own knowledge as a reg-tech data scientist specifically in the finance industry, so I am not going to source:

A blacklist is a list of untrustworthy people who should be excluded from [something].

In this case, they should be excluded from being **lent more money** i.e. excluded from being given credit.

Essentially, the sentence means:

> If you default on payments (i.e. fail to keep up with loan repayments) then you are unlikely to be accepted by the lender (whose payment you have defaulted on) for another loan (they will add you to their credit blacklist).

Comment: nb: "loan" rather than "lone"

Comment: And whose rather than who's.